# Помогите с задачей на условный оператор, не проходит один тест

Tags: python, операторы

*Проблема в том, что решение не проходит один тест (из 10), вероятно, здесь есть очевидная ошибка... Но я ее не вижу)*

Задача должна быть написана без использования циклов.

Вы сидите на первом сидении в маршрутном такси. Проезд в маршрутке стоит 10 рублей. Вам передают купюры достоинством в 10, 50 и 100 рублей (с каждой купюры – на билет за одного пассажира). Часть из них вы можете сразу раздать в качестве сдачи (её можно выдать полностью или частично). Остальные купюры вы передаете водителю. Какое наименьшее количество купюр вам придется передать водителю?

**Входные данные**

Вводится три целых неотрицательных числа (каждое не превосходит 100) – количество 10-, 50- и 100-рублевых купюр, которые вам передали.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите одно число – наименьшее возможное количество купюр, которое придется передать водителю.

**Мое решение**

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())

res, d = a + b + c, c * 9 + b * 4

if c - b >= 0:
    res -= b
    c -= b
    b *= 2
else:
    res -= c
    b += c
    c = 0

if a - d >= 0:
    res -= d
else:
    res -= a

print(res)
```

**Примеры**

```
1 1 1 - 1
9 0 2 - 2
```

Comment: Пока не совсем понял алгоритм. 10 1 1 в ответе у вас получается один, а должно быть 3. И еще в первом условии меняются b и c, но дальше они не используются. Сейчас будем разбираться.

Comment: Поправка 10 1 1 должно быть 2.

Comment: Я не понял алгоритм какой смысл вычитать b из c или наоборот?

Comment: Это "обмен" купюр, т.е. их номинала.

Comment: Я понял агоритм. Сначала нужно тем кто сдавал по 100 вернуть 10 по максимуму, и если еще есть то 50 с учетом возможности. Потом тем кто сдавал 50 вернуть 10. Тогда это оптимально будет. А вы по моему сначала 50 возвращаете что не оптимально. Сейчас попробую в питоне написать решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот алгоритм должен быть правильный. Проверьте.

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())

cup=a+b+c #количество купюр которое мы будем платить

#возвращаем сдачу заплатившим по 100 купюрами по 10
#тк чем больше купюр возвратим тем меньше нужно заплатить

d=min(9*c,a) #столько 10 можно будет вернуть на сдачу
a-=d
cup-=d
c-=d//9
if d%9>4:
    #если последнему заплатившему по 100 вернут больше 4 по 10 то ему нельзя будет отдать далее 50
    c-=1

#возвращаем оставшимся заплатившим 100 сдачу по 50
d=min(c,b) #столько 50 можно будет вернуть на сдачу
cup-=d

#возвращаем тем кто платил по 50 оставшимися 10
d=min(4*b,a) #столько 10 можно будет вернуть на сдачу
cup-=d

print(cup)
```

Comment: Я тут. Суть в том, что по условию задачи она должна быть решена без циклов, что осложняет ситуацию.

Comment: У меня неправильный алгоритм. Если 2 по 100 дадут то должно быть 2 купюры. Нельзя же одну сотню заплатить а другую сразу вернуть.

Comment: Так вы не написали что нужно без циклов.

Comment: Извините, не заметил. Сейчас добавлю

Comment: Поменял алгоритм

Comment: Пройдено 9 из 10 тестов. Ладно, и так сойдет) Спасибо за помощь!